# Find all matches in a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

My input is

```
This is <a> <test> mat<ch>.
```

Output should be

```
1. <a>
2. <test>
3. <ch>
```

I have tried this

```
string input1 = "This is <a> <test> mat<ch>.";
var m1 = Regex.Matches(input1, @"<(.*)>");
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in m1)
{
    list.Add(match.Value);
}
```

This returns `<a> <test> mat<ch>` as single element in list.

Comment: Just use `list = Regex.Matches(input1, @"<[^<>]*>").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();`. Do not use `.*?`, it is not effecient as compared with a negated character  class.

Comment: What output should be for input like : `<test<a<b>>>` ?

Comment: not sure who closed this, this is not a duplicate..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make your regex non greedy

```
var m1 = Regex.Matches(input1, @"<(.*?)>");
```

Or use negation based regex

```
var m1 = Regex.Matches(input1, @"<([^>]*)>");
```

Comment: @vks This solution worked. Can you please tell what is the significance of ? in this regex?

Comment: @TBAG when you use `?` it will stop at the first instance of `>` .If you dont it will be greedy and will go upto last instance of `>`

Comment: in your regex `<(.*)>` the part `.*` will try to match as long as possible. since `.` is any character including `>` then it will go until last `>` character thus will give you all matches at once. when you use `.*?` is will match as least as possible so when you reach first `>` thats the part of the pattern so it will stop there and first match becomes `<a>` forexample @TBAG

Comment: Note that this regex will not match balanced angle brackets. Can you have any?

Comment: @stribizhev did explain in comments..waiting for OP if he needs more

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary what does `Don't be so green eyed` mean?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary no worries, I figured it was something along those lines due to the color, just curious.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the following regex

```
(<.*?>)
  //^^ Using Non greedy
```

If there's any case like of `<test<a<b>>>`

then you can simply use

```
(<[^>]>)
```

Output:

```
<b>
```